# Maximum value per each group

Tags: python, pandas

```
      A    B
0   Red  3.9
1   Red  4.1
2   Red  2.3
3  Blue -1.2
4  Blue -9.2
5  Blue -6.1
```

I want to create a new `df['C']` with maximum `B` value, per each `A` group.

Output should be:

```
      A    B    C
0   Red  3.9  4.1
1   Red  4.1  4.1
2   Red  2.3  4.1
3  Blue -1.2 -1.2
4  Blue -9.2 -1.2
5  Blue -6.1 -1.2
```

I´ve tried:

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].max()
```

Comment: Doesn't look like a basic python question? Are you using a third party library? If so I would suggest you to add that information and also add a tag.

Comment: I guess he wants to map out the max values by the groups as a new column but the duplicate doesnt answer that fully. you can try this `max = df.groupby('A')['B'].max().reset_index()`
`max.columns =['A', 'C']`
`df1 = pd.merge(df, max, on='A')`

Comment: No need to merge. Just use transform as indicated in the duplicate.